# How to create quote and order programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, quote, quoteitem

I try to create an order programmatically in magento2 using this code snippet found on webkul.com

this is the order that i want to create:

```
$tempOrder=[
     'currency_id'=> 'USD',
     'email'=> 'test@webkul.com', //buyer email id
     'shipping_address' =>[
            'firstname'=> 'jhon', //address Details
            'lastname'=> 'Deo',
                    'street' => 'xxxxx',
                    'city' => 'xxxxx',
            'country_id' => 'IN',
            'region' => 'xxx',
            'postcode' => '43244',
            'telephone' => '52332',
            'fax' => '32423',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
             ],
   'items'=> [ //array of product which order you want to create
              ['product_id'=>'1','qty'=>1],
              ['product_id'=>'2','qty'=>2]
            ]
];
```

and this is where i processed it

```
<?php
namespace YourNameSpace\ModuleName\Helper;
 
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
     /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    * @param Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey $formkey,
    * @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    * @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    * @param Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService  
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
 
    /**
     * Create Order On Your Store
     * 
     * @param array $orderData
     * @return array
     * 
    */
    public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
 
        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }
 
        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
 
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
 
        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
 
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
 
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
 
        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
        
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
        }else{
            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
 
?>
```

code work fine, but i messed around with method `$quote->addProduct`.
I don't know why that adding more than one product create an order with just one product and all quantity summed to this

Answer (score 3):

**Solved**

the issues was that i use `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` instead of `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` in the constructor.

and so foreach became

```
foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
     $product = $this->_product->create()->load($item['product_id']);
     $product->setPrice($item['price']);
     $quote->addProduct(
           $product,
           intval($item['qty'])
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class OrderCreateTest extends Action {
    protected $_quoteFactory;
    protected $_orderModel;
    protected $_productModel;
    protected $_customerRepository;
    protected $_quoteManagementModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagementModel,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->_quoteFactory         = $quoteFactory;
        $this->_orderModel           = $orderModel;
        $this->_productModel         = $productModel;
        $this->_customerRepository   = $customerRepository;
        $this->_quoteManagementModel = $quoteManagementModel;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try {
            $customerId = $storeId = 1;
            $customer   = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $quote      = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
            $product    = $this->_productModel->load(1);

            $quote->setStoreId($storeId);
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
            $quote->addProduct($product);
            $quote->setCustomerEmail('roni_cost@example.com');

            $addressData = [
                "firstname"  => "Test",
                "lastname"   => "Test",
                "street"     => "Sample Street 10",
                "city"       => "Somewhere",
                "postcode"   => "123456",
                "telephone"  => "123456",
                "country_id" => "US",
                "region_id"  => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
            ];

            $billingAddress  = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                            ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
            $quote->getPayment()->setQuote($quote);
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
            $quote->save();

            $order = $this->_quoteManagementModel->submit($quote);

            echo "<pre>ORDER DATA";
            echo $order->getId();
            exit;

            exit;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i test you're code and i've got the same issues if i try to add more than one product

Comment: Can anyone help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7