# Update shipping address programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento-2.1, quote

Basically the store have 4 currency and when user change currency the default shipping country should be updated.
Example

- USD - shipping country USA
- GBP - shipping country UK
- EUR - shipping country Ireland
- INR - shipping country India

how can i programmatically update shipping country in user quote.

Comment: Get current country & load respective currency.

Comment: I want to know how to set shipping country. as "Get current country & load respective currency" dont set the shipping country to current country

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2 or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123752/how-to-create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: Go to `vendor\magento\module-quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface.php` & check `setCountryId` method. Then use `$quote = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote'); & set Value`

Comment: you mean $quote->setCountryId('US');

Comment: Yes. It's not working?